Is $ W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ equal to $ W^{k,p}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n) $?
I have some questions because of the uses of Theorem 1 in Section 5.3 from Evans' PDE book. Here's the statement of this theorem:

Theorem 1 (Local approximation by smooth functions). Assume $ u\in W^{k,p}(U) $ for some $ 1\le p<\infty $, and set $$ u^\varepsilon=\eta_\varepsilon\ast u\text{ in }U_\varepsilon. $$ Then (i) $ u^\varepsilon\in C^\infty(U_\varepsilon) $ for each $ \varepsilon>0 $, and (ii) $ u^\varepsilon\to u $ in $ W^{k,p}_{loc}(U) $, as $ \varepsilon\to0 $.

In this theorem, $ u^\varepsilon=\eta_\varepsilon\ast u $ is the convolution, $ \eta_\varepsilon $ is the standard mollifier (see Evans' PDE, appendix C) and $ U_\varepsilon=\{x\in U:dist(x,\partial U)>\varepsilon\} $.
If $ U=\mathbb{R}^n $, I understand that we can assume that $ U_\varepsilon=\mathbb{R}^n $ for all $ \varepsilon>0 $. In fact, the definition of $ U_\varepsilon $ doesn't make sense with $ U=\mathbb{R}^n $, because its boundary is empty and there isn't a definition of the distance between a point and a empty set. However, the sequence of sets $ U_\varepsilon $ must "converge" to $ U $, so I will assume that $ U=\mathbb{R}^n $ implies that $ U_\varepsilon=\mathbb{R}^n $.
My question is about the uses of Theorem 1 in other theorems from the same book:

Theorem 2 in Section 5.6: at the beginning of the proof, he says by Theorem 1 in Section 5.3 that a certain sequence of functions converges in $ W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ (but the statement of Theorem 1 in Section 5.3, in this particular case, talks about $ W^{1,p}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ instead of $ W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) $).
The same problem can be found in the proof of Theorem 5 in Section 5.6.

So, my questions are the following:

Is $ W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ equal to $ W^{1,p}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n) $? Why?
Which conditions are required to $ W^{1,p}(\Omega)=W^{1,p}_{loc}(\Omega) $?
Which conditions are required to $ W^{k,p}(\Omega)=W^{k,p}_{loc}(\Omega) $?


These spaces $W^{k,p}_{loc}(\Omega)$ and $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ are never equal for open sets $\Omega$. The problem is that for these loc-spaces the behavior close to the boundary (and at infinity) cannot be controlled.
Think of $\Omega=(0,1)$, $u(x) = \frac1x$. Then $u\in W^{k,p}_{loc}(\Omega)$ for all $k$ and $p$, but certainly not in all $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.
For $\Omega = \mathbb R^d$ take $u(x)\equiv 1$, which is in all  $W^{k,p}_{loc}(\Omega)$ but in no $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ with $p<\infty$.
The use of the loc-space in the local approximation theorem is due to the same problem, as one cannot prove convergence of the approximation close to the boundary. (The mollification $(\eta_\epsilon \ast u)(x)$  for $x$ close to the boundary has to take values of $u$ outside of $\Omega$ into account.)
For $\Omega = \mathbb R^d$ there is no such problem. Here, one has convergence $\eta_\epsilon \ast u \to u$ in $W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^d)$.
